# How to turn on the 'on-the-fly' functionality with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Before `QgsMapRenderer` was deprecated if we wanted to activate OTF we used code like this:

```
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
canvas.mapRenderer().setProjectionsEnabled(True)
```

Currently, `QgsMapRenderer` is divided into two classes `QgsMapSettings` and `QgsMapRendererJob`. I did some research, but with no success. So how we can achieve the same now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable 'on the fly' CRS transformation in QGIS 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282115/enable-on-the-fly-crs-transformation-in-qgis-3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this will be possible as according to one of the QGIS devs [@ndawson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/28443/ndawson) in response to [Feature request #11644](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/11644):

> *"Disabling on the fly projection is no longer an option in QGIS 3.0"*

Comment: So, you are saying that even this class is deprecated I can use it anyway?

Comment: @DIVAD - Edited my post :)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for, despite that it's not a good information (at least for me :) ).

Comment: @DIVAD - Most welcome, hopefully it won't affect you too much ;)