# Enable 'on the fly' CRS transformation in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

In QGIS 2.8 there is a clear button to 'enable on the fly CRS transformation' in the "project properties" for a new project.  Seen here:
[image]

But in QGIS 3.0, I cannot find it to save my life.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: It is on by default https://issues.qgis.org/issues/11644

Comment: I couldn't comment on the comment from gisnside but I found it to be very useful +1 if I could. Also I agree with AnsreasK, being able to turn off OTF would be very help to quickly identify layers with different projections as I do this often.

Comment: It would be great if someone could update the documentation and tutorials for 3.x that still refer to enabling OTF transformations. https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html?highlight=otf#define-on-the-fly-otf-crs-transformation

Comment: I have used on the fly reprojections for a few years with QGIS and it always worked very well until the NOOSA release. Now when I bring in raster files they don't reproject to the county coordinate systems that I have used for years. They used to in older versions of QGIS. It doesn't seem to matter if I bring in the rasters from and ESRI server or a local server. Has any one else had this problem or found a solution other than installing an older version of QGIS?

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS SE! This would be better suited as submitted as a separate question (with link to this one) explaining what issues, expected behaviour you're having and version of QGIS (see also:https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) . We try and keep the answers on post as specific answers to the question at hand. Thanks!

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162938)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162938)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In QGIS 3.0, on-the-fly (OTF) reprojection is always enabled (https://issues.qgis.org/issues/11644).

Comment: There is no option anymore to deactivate the the OTF? This is crazy! For a GIS program this is ridiculous.

Comment: @AndreasK Can you list any cases when OTF reprojection should NOT be used?

Comment: Every time when there is the possibility that your layers are in a different coordinate system! With the OTF ON&OFF you could immediately see that you have layers with different coordinate systems in your project. As I gave courses to hundreds of people, I know that people look for super-easy ways. That said QGIS3 is in many many way more complicated (more clicks) than QGIS2. The new checkbox (instead of OTF!!!) --> "No Projection" is almost unexplainable and doesn't make sense in 99.999% of all cases.

Comment: Deactivating this option is good to see the source coordinates :  I support the fact it's very useful. @AndreasK the workaround is just to select "no projection" for your project ;)