# QGIS vectors and rasters

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, vector

I have created a map with polygon shapefiles and am trying to import them onto an different raster but when I do they are larger than the raster image and are far away. What am I doing wrong? My intention is to overlap the shapefiles to show different terrain because I am dealing with wetlands and ecosystems.

Comment: What coordinate system is defined in your canvas; do you have project-on-the-fly enabled? Do both shapefile and raster have a defined coordinate system?

Comment: They both have the same coordinates EPSG: 4326 WGS 84, I don't have project on the fly enabled that I know of. New to QGIS so I did not activate it so I assume it nots on.

Comment: This one might help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282115/enable-on-the-fly-crs-transformation-in-qgis-3 but from the sounds of it one of your datasets has the wrong coordinate system defined. When you look at the coordinates in the lower right corner of the frame what sort of numbers are you getting?

Comment: The vectors are in the 5000+ range while the raster is in the 300+ range. Waaay off. Also project fly on the wall is always enabled as I am using QGIS 3.0

Comment: Even 300 is a bit too big, EPSG:4326 - WGS84 Geographic goes from x -180 to 180 and y -90 to 90. Have a closer look at where you got the vectors and raster from and try to establish what is the correct coordinate reference system they should have.