# DEM not showing when loaded

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, dem, qgis-3

I'm very new to QGIS, but in the past days I've created 3 different maps. I have now downloaded DEM data in ASC format, and when I open it as a raster file in a new QGIS project there is no problem, I switch it to hillshade and it displays perfectly. The problem is when I want to have this DEM in the same file as my 3 maps (polygons). It loads, but it is not visible.

If I open my 3 maps and then load my DEM, the DEM doesn't show. And if I open the DEM in a new blank file, and I load my polygons from my 3 maps, the polygons don't show. It's as if they're not compatible with each other.

I've also opened the DEM in ASC format and exported it as GeoTIFF, and afterwards I loaded the GeoTIFF format into the file where my maps are, but the the DEM still doesn't appear.

Comment: I assume your DEM shows up somewhere in nowhere on your map. Use zoom on layer to check this. Then I'd suggest to check georeference of your layers and their CRS.

Comment: @MrXsquared Hi, thanks for your answer. The problem is that georeferencing isn't necessary, it's already been done by the people who made it. And the DEM is also huge, it wouldn't be small at all.

Comment: I meant it might have the wrong crs assigned.

Comment: Or no CRS assigned and the project/other layers have a different CRS.

Comment: @MrXsquared Oh okay! And could you explain what CRS is and how to assign the correct one?

Comment: We can start with this: Where did you get your DEM from? And where is your DEM located at and where should it be located at?

Answer (score 1):

Try this check-up of the situation:

1. Right-click on every layer name, go to "zoom to layer". If you
   can't see the same position of polygons layer on the map, the
   problem is coordinate reference system of layer.
2. Set the correct crs for each layer of your maps (righ-click on the layer name > Set CRS).
3. If you're using QGIS 2.8 or earlier check "[enable on-the fly CRS transformation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282115/enable-on-the-fly-crs-transformation-in-qgis-3)".

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. 
Now I know what CRS is, but the program asks me to set the CRS when I open the DEM into the project. Anyway, I've set the CRS again, but nothing changes.

Comment: Can you write here the two EPSG code of the layers?

Comment: I have the same problem, and it isn't related to the CRS. I created a new GeoTIFF file from DEM data. Everything was ok in the first session after it finished processing, but when I tried to load the file in a new session, it didn't show. The file appears in the Layers tab, but is grayed out and doesn't show the raster value range as it should. In the symbology settings, it shows the image in greyscale in the "Thumbnail" window, and when I zoom to location, it merely zooms out above my other layer, where it should be. It just doesn't show.